# How many ways can 2 people exchange items of equal value so that they always have an equal sum?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, permutations

This question is based on a [dynamic programming problem on TopCoder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=ProblemDetail&rd=4705&pm=1166) that I have been trying to understand forever.

The main concept that I can't understand or even begin to formulate is the following-:

**Problem Statement:**

Given a tuple of $n$ items $A = \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$, where each item is of equal value, i.e. $a_1 = a_2, a_2 = a_3, ...$ and so on.

How many ways are there for two people to pick items from the tuple $A$, such that they always have **equal cumulative value on both sides**?

**Example:**

$A = \{5,5,5,5\}$

**Solution (not exhaustive)-:**

$\{5\},\{5\}$ (first 5 and second 5)

$\{5\},\{5\}$ (first 5 and third 5)

$\{5\},\{5\}$ (first 5 and fourth 5)

$\{5,5\}$ and $\{5,5\}$ (first 5 second 5 and third 5 and fourth 5)

$\{5,5\}$ and $\{5,5\}$ (first 5 third 5 and second 5 and fourth 5)

so on

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you give an example or otherwise clarify the question?

Comment: If each item has equal value, then the value doesn't matter at all, but you're just looking at how many items they have picked. So the two people just have to pick the same number of items, let's say each picks $k$ items from $n$. In total, they have taken $2k$ items out of $n$ ...

Comment: You identify the items with their values. Is that correct in this context? If $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_n=a$ then $A=\{a\}$ so only contains one item.

Comment: @Christoph I have edited the question to include an example

Comment: @drhab no the set contains $n$ items all of which are identical to each other. It would not be correct in this context to say that the set only contains one item.

Comment: @MattiP. I am interested on how many ways this can be done. See my example in the edit.

Comment: @ng.newbie Then it is wrong to use the word "set" here. If in a set all elements are equal then the set contains at most one element. You better speak of a tuple $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$

Comment: @drhab Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to having a set of $n$ items and choosing an ordered pair of two disjoint subsets of equal size. For a fixed size $k\le \frac{n}{2} $ the number of ways to choose two disjoint subsets is
$$
\binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{k}.
$$
Summing over all possible $k$ yields.
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{k}.
$$
More on these numbers might be found in the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (A180282)](http://oeis.org/A180282).

If you include the choice of both sets being empty, you have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{k},
$$
which is [A002426](http://oeis.org/A002426) in the OEIS.

Comment: If I were t to ask you the intuition behind the above formula could you answer it here or does that demand a different question?

Comment: There are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose $k$ elements from a set of $n$ elements. After that you have $n-k$ elements left and want to choose $k$ of them again.